# bootstrap row > column selection issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What I want to do is remove the last child border from this column, but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```css
.softdev-per{
    margin-top: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    border-right: 2px solid $color-light-blue;
}

.softdev-per:nth-last-child(){
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-3">
         <div class="softdev-per">
          <p>+<span>35</span>%</p>
          <p>lead 1</p>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="softdev-per">
         <p>+<span>60</span>%</p>
         <p>lead 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="softdev-per">
         <p>+<span>25</span>%</p>
         <p>lead 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="softdev-per">
         <p>+<span>28</span>%</p>
         <p>lead 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

all I want to do is to remove the last child border-right but it doesn't work.

Comment: What css preprocessor are you using?

Comment: i am using scss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:nth-last-child()` expects an expression inside parentheses, you're most likely looking for just `:last-child`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

> `:nth-last-child( <nth> [ of <complex-selector-list> ]? )`

Comment from author:

> its working without bootstrap row column , but it doesn't work when I
> add row column from boostrap .

it is because you need to set the last-child in `.col-lg-3` instead of `.softdev-per`,

something like this:

```
.col-lg-3:last-child .softdev-per{ /* code */}
```

Comment: its working without bootstrap row column , but it doesn't work when i add row column from boostrap .

Comment: yes , its also work your way too , thank you so much dippas , i was just a bit confused from :nth:last-child() at first , now i understand what is the difference :)

Answer (score -2):

i fixed the problem by adding a class inside column then select it with css with :nth-last-child(1) , and it worked .

like this :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 softdev-percentage">

 .softdev-percentage:nth-last-child(1) .softdev-perc{
    border-right: none;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't add classes to built-in classes from bootstrap, and there is no need to use `nth-las-child(1)` when `:last-child` it is more human readable